# Ansi SQL for timestamp to intervals query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, timestamp, ansi-sql

Let's say I have a table which tells me when a certain thing was activated and deactivated:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[active] 
( 
    [timestamp] [DATETIME] NOT NULL, 
    [activated] [BIT] NOT NULL 
)
```

And my best attempt at making a query against this to retrieve the intervals for which the thing was active:

```
SELECT a.timestamp AS 'ActivatedDate', 
       Deactivated.timestamp 
FROM   active a 
       OUTER apply (SELECT Min(d.timestamp) AS TimeStamp 
                    FROM   active d 
                    WHERE  activated = 0 
                           AND d.timestamp > a.timestamp) AS Deactivated 
WHERE  a.activated = 1
```

I need to rewrite this so that it will work with ANSI SQL, or at least both T-SQL and Oracle 9. It is my understanding that OUTER apply wont work for Oracle 9.

If there is a much better way to do this sort of thing, please share! :)

I need this to check if certain events were happening while this thing was enabled/disabled. Thanks!

Comment: The ANSI equivalent of `OUTER APPLY` is a `JOIN LATERAL` (but Postgres and HSQLDB are the only ones supporting that)

Comment: Btw: Oracle 9 has been deprecated a long time ago, you shouldn't be using that.

Comment: I'm not using that, but some of my customers are, or may be. It's all about what promisses of compatibility was made at some previous date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.timestamp as ActivatedDate,
       (select min(d.timestamp)
        from active d
        where d.activated = 0 and
              d.timestamp > a.timestamp
       ) as DeactivedDate
from active a
where a.activated = 1;
```

This is ANSI SQL and it should work in SQL Server and Oracle (and almost all other databases).

Do note:  there may be more efficient ways to do what you want in any given database.

Comment: Dang. Now I feel so extremely stupid.. :) Thanks. Will accept when it allows me to.

Comment: @Mithon . . . This is a rather subtle query for most people.  You shouldn't feel stupid.